# How to enable full touch keyboard layout on Windows 10 touch screen machine?

Tags: windows, touchpad

I'm working on updating WIM image for touch screen terminals and requirement came to show touch keyboard in full mode out of the box. Below is a default image
[image]

I'm looking for the setting to display keyboard layout like this
[image]

I used ProcMon to get a trace while switching KB mode, but couldn't find anything meaningful so far.

Searching on the internet mostly returns result on OSK - On screen keyboard, which is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which keyboard layouts are you switching? Is this question about burning a certain layout into the OOB experience?

Comment: this is for touchpad keyboard, you can see the icon in the system tray in the second screenshot. This setup is requirement for any user of the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took another Procmon trace which helped me to figure out that the touchpad keyboard layout is stored in  `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Packages\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\Settings\Settings.dat` file

So, I mounted my `.WIM` image with DISM tools and copied this file from pre-configured user profile to the Default profile and committed the changes.

I applied the image, created new user and it worked, this user got the desired keyboard layout.

I want to thank everyone for help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The settings of the Windows 10 touch keyboard are found under the
registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7`.

- Value `EnableCompatibilityKeyboard` is `1` for enabling
  switching to the full layout.
  Value `KeyboardLayoutPreference` controls the default opened
  layout, your value might be `1`.
- Value `DisableNewKeyboardExperience` is `1` for the old
  keyboard style.
- Value `UserKeyboardScalingFactor` is the touch keyboard size,
  a number between 20 (smaller) to 200 (larger).

All the values are of type DWORD 32.

The first point might be what you are looking for,
but the others may also be useful.

Comment: He's not looking for **larger** but for the full/standard/traditional keyboard layout with all the keys and a separate number row.

Comment: @YisroelTech: I added everything I found.

Comment: Might be all that there is, but I don't think that any of them is addressing his question.

Comment: @YisroelTech: I think there is a good chance for `EnableCompatibilityKeyboard`, but I can't test it.

Comment: As far as the description goes for this everywhere, this only enables it as an option to be selected on the touch keyboard. The question was about having it as a default (as he was already *switching KB mode*.)

Comment: @YisroelTech: OK, I unearthed another one. Some tests by the user are required here.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting conundrum arose that is related to this issue.
During a recent update, Microsoft made the full standard keyboard the default option. Making the original "default" with the less keys obsolete.

This caused an issue for our kiosked images as we want to restrict access to esc, winkey, function keys, TAB, CAPS lock and the ALT key.

We REALLY need to revert to the aforementioned smaller touch keyboard as it has created security flaws in our production kiosks in the field.

Wonderful of Microsoft to "fix" something that isn't broken!!